# RadDateTimePicker - Time visible but not editable

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, datetimepicker

I would like to know if there is a way to see and not modify the time in the datetimePicker while the date can be changed.
EXAMPLE: When loading the view date is 18/03/2017 10:30,then click on the dateTimePicker and select the date 19/03/2018 (the time picker should be disable but set to 10:30) and at the end i have the date 19/03/2018 10:30.
Is there a solution? Thanks in advance!!
my control is this:

```
<telerik:RadDateTimePicker Margin="0,0,10,0"
                                               Grid.Column="0"
                                               Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                               SelectableDateStart="{Binding DataMinima}"
                                               StartTime="{Binding OraMinima}"
                                               SelectedValue="{Binding DataAppuntamento, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                               TimeInterval="0:30"
                                               Culture="it"
                                               TodayButtonVisibility="Visible"
                                               DateTimeWatermarkContent="Data/Ora Appuntamento"
                                               ToolTipService.ToolTip="Data/Ora Appuntamento"
                                               ErrorTooltipContent="Errore"
                                               Width="200"
                                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                               Height="25"
                                               Visibility="{Binding IsProduttori,Converter={StaticResource ConvertBooleanToVisibleNegato}}"/>
```

Comment: Does it work if you set `InputMode` explicitly? https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/raddatetimepicker/features/input-modes

Comment: No because u can't see the time